# Get closest value to AVG TSQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(AVG([DC].[ContractedAmount]) , '$###,###,###,###.##') AS [AverageContractedAmount]
FROM 
    [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
INNER JOIN 
    [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
```

As you can see I get the `Average` of Contracted Amount. I get something like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| [AverageContractedAmount] |
+---------------------------+
| $1,000.00                 |
+---------------------------+
```

Now I want to get project who is more closest to that value

For example if I have 5 projects in project table like:

```
+----------------+
|  ProjectName   |
+----------------+
| First Project  |
| Second Project |
| Third Project  |
| Four Project   |
| Five Project   |
+----------------+
```

Relation of `[DC]` with project is something like this:

```
+----------------+------------------+
|  ProjectName   | ContractedAmount |
+----------------+------------------+
| First Project  |              500 |
| Second Project |              700 |
| Third Project  |              300 |
| Four Project   |              950 |
| Five Project   |              800 |
+----------------+------------------+
```

I want the query to return the `Four Project Name` because its `ContractedAmount` value is the closest to the `AVG` value. How can I achieve this? Regards

Comment: Closest without going over or closest?

Comment: Closest, don't care if its over for example it can be 1001 I want project who have 1001 because is more closest than 950 @SeanLange

Comment: What if you have multiples that are closest? Do you want to return all of them or just one? And if one, which one?

Comment: That I understand your question is if I have two projects with same value supossing Project 1 =  1001 and Project 2 = 1001 too, I want to select just one, I mean just SELECT TOP 1 @SeanLange

Comment: Right. So which one is TOP 1? You might have one that is over and one that is under. Or two that are under and one over. For TOP to be used correctly you need an order by and it needs to be robust enough to be consistent. TOP 1 among 3 values that are the same is not consistent.

Comment: What value is first is not relevant for final pruposes, I want to get wichever. @SeanLange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without putting much thought into this, you can just dump that into a subquery and subtract, sort by the difference, and keep the top result:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    project_name,

FROM Project
ORDER BY Abs(ContractedAmount - 
        (
            SELECT
            AVG([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [AverageContractedAmount]
             FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
                             INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
                             INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
                             INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
                             INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
                             INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
        )) ASC
```

Comment: Simplest solution (based on the finished query for average) that would probably work. Just needs some more joins in the outer select query because the contracted amount seems to be in the `DesignCustomer` table.

Comment: This returns me one row with two columns: project_name and  contractedAmount, what I need to do to get only project_name column?

Comment: Updated to move the math into the group by

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've already figured out getting your average, so taking your sample tables, but fudged to get an average of $1000, I wrote a single select statement using the average to get your answer. For this answer, I've just calculated the average from the table rather than your code in order to get the variable @AVERAGE.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Amts (Project VARCHAR(20), Amount INT);

    INSERT INTO #Amts 
    VALUES

    ('One Project', 500),
    ('Two Project', 1500),
    ('Three Project', 300),
    ('Four Project', 1700),
    ('Five Project', 1100),
    ('Six Project', 900)        ;

    DECLARE @AVERAGE INT = (SELECT AVG(Amount) FROM #Amts) -- $1000

    SELECT    TOP 1 Project -- Since you said whichever project is suitable, this should be fine. 
    FROM      #Amts AS A
    WHERE     ABS(A.Amount - @AVERAGE) = (SELECT MIN(ABS(Amin.Amount - @AVERAGE)) FROM #Amts AS Amin)
    ORDER BY  Project

    DROP TABLE #Amts
```

This gives you the answer of "Five Project".

Answer (score 0):

Strictly closest would be:

```
; WITH AvgAmt AS (
    SELECT AVG([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [AverageContractedAmount]
    FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
        INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
        INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
        INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
        INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
        INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
)
SELECT TOP(1) P.ProjectName, DC.ContractedAmount
FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
    INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
    INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
    INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
ORDER BY ABS(AvgAmt.[AverageContractedAmount] - ContractedAmount);
```

Depending on your data, you might want to exclude a few `INNER JOIN`'s from the CTE itself simply to improve performance if the data doesn't require it.

The solution can also be easily parametrized to select closest `@n` contracted amounts instead of the closest one (converting `SELECT TOP(1)` to `SELECT TOP(@n)`).

As an addition, if there are multiple projects with the same difference to the average contracted amount, you might want to add some other columns into `ORDER BY` to break the tie. This is something you can decide on as the one with the knowledge of what data represents and what you expect from it.

Answer (score 0):

using DENSE_RANK:

```
WITH getavg AS (
SELECT AVG([DC].[ContractedAmount]) OVER() AS [AverageContractedAmount]
, p.projectname, p.contractedamount
 FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
                     INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
                     INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
                     INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
                     INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
                     INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]

),

ranked as (
SELECT projectname, contractedamount
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ABS([AverageContractedAmount]-contractedamount)) AS dr
FROM getavg)

SELECT * FROM ranked
WHERE dr <= 5
```

Comment: `WHERE` clause isn't aware of the `SELECT`. You need to wrap that into a second CTE and then filter by the `dr` column in a third select statement.